# How do I get data from one function to another

Tags: python-3.x, function

I read about "random" and it got me thinking about helping my kid in reading and writing by making a program where a word is shown and she needs to type it. Because it's a small program I could do it quite easliy with procedural programming, but to make it more 'attractive' to her I decided to fool around with tkinter.

Tkinter forces to create functions which can be called through 'command' and now I have a problem.. If I run the check() function, it doesn't get the variables from the dictee() function. I found several answer from nesting a function in a function (undefined variable problems), or passing arguments with return (ended up in recursion), using global (the list of words wouldn't empty) etc etc.. I couldn't get any of them working... I've been looking for answers, but I can't find the correct solution.. Anyone care to shed their light?

Thanks!

```
"""import nescessary."""
import sys
import random

def main():
    """Setting up the game"""
    print("Aliyahs reading game.'\n")
    begin = input("do you want to start? yes or no.\n\n")
    if begin == "yes":
        dictee()

def dictee():
    """Show random words and ask for input."""
    words_correct = 0
    words_wrong = 0
    vocabulary = ['kip', 'hok', 'bal', 'muis', 'gat'
        ]
    words_passed = []
    while True:
        if vocabulary == []:
            print("\n\nThose were all the words.")
            print("Words correct: %d" % words_correct)
            print("words wrong: %d" % words_wrong)
            one_more_time = input("Do you want to go again? yes or no")
            if one_more_time == "no":
                print("See you next time.")
                input("\nPush enter to close.")
                sys.exit()
            else:
                main()
        word = random.choice(vocabulary)
        print('\x1b[2J')
        print("{}".format(word))
        print("\n\n")
        words_passed.append("{}".format(word))
        vocabulary.remove("{}".format(word))
        answer = input("Write the word you saw:\n\n")
        check()

def check():
    '''Cross check word shown with answer given'''
    if answer == word:
        print("Nice")
        words_correct += 1
    else:
        print("2bad")
        words_wrong += 1

    try_again = input("\n\nContinue? yes or no\n ")

    if try_again.lower() == "no":
        exit_game()
    else:
        dictee()


def exit_game():
    '''summarize results and exit after pushing enter'''
    print("Words correct: %d" % words_correct)
    print("Words wrong: %d" % words_wrong)
    input("\nPress Enter to exit.")
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Where is your Tkinter setup?  You need to define the tkinter window and place the widgets within the window.  You can then call the functions from each widget to accomplish your goal.  see [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html) for a good intro to tkinter

Comment: @itprorh66 this is without the tkinter module. I think I need this to work first. Tkinter is a different challenge :-)

Comment: Technically speaking you just need `global` or I think even using parameters will work here.

Comment: @cool cloud,.thank you for your reply. Like i mentioned in my introduction, I've also used global. Maybe I'm using it wrong, but it messes up other things like the list of words and the counters. How would you use it?

Comment: It would be easier if you could include an English version of the program so we could run it over and understand it

Comment: Your code example doesn't seem to use tkinter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just made few changes here, and run it and got no errors because I dont know what to type in order to get the right results. Anyways all the changes are related to `global` and redefinition of values.

```
# say these outside all the functions, in the main block
words_correct = 0
words_wrong = 0 
vocabulary = ['kip', 'hok', 'bal', 'muis', 'gat'] 
words_passed = [] 

def dictee():
    global word, answer
..... #same bunch of codes
def check():
    global answer, words_correct, words_wrong
.... #same bunch of codes
```

**Why do we have to say `global`?** Basically because when we define variables they either get defined on local scope or global scope, variables defined on main block(outside of all function) are on global scope, while inside functions are on local scope. Variables defined on global scope can be accessed anywhere and that on local can only be accessed from within where its defined.

**Where do we have to use `global`?** We say global where we define the variable or we redefine, or at least this is what I know of. We need to say `global` where we declare the variable, like, `a = 'good'`, we also need to say `global` if we are changing it, `a = 'bad'` or `a += 'day'` because we are assigning a new value to it. Using global outside of all functions, on the main block, is useless.

**Why are we declaring `words_correct` and `words_wrong` outside all functions?** It is simply because if you declare and set its value to 0 inside `dictee()`, each time the function is run the value of those variables will change to 0, which means score will always be 0 or 1, so we define it once only, in the main block. Same logic applies to the two lists(`vocabulary` and `words_passed`), each time function runs they reset the list to the full list of words, so to get rid of that, just define it once in the main block.

I also think using parameters here might need re-structuring of your code as your calling both function from each other.

**Note that we only say `global` on functions, out side functions all defined variables are open to global scope and can be accessed from anywhere in the code.**

PS: This is just my understanding of global over the span of 4 months, do correct me if im wrong anywhere, thanks :D

Comment: :) thank you for your reply. That's how I understood global as well. And I tried it like you mention it before, what happens is is that for some reason it does not remove the items in the list of words, so you can never finish. And I don't understand how the global effects the command to remove the word from the list and add it to a list of words_passed. Sorry about the Dutch content. What it basicaly does is that is shows a word, asks for input, check if the word and input are the same and asks to continue. When the answer is no, or the list is empty it summarises the score and you can exit.

Comment: also, it doesn't count the score anymore.. so (as far as I understand), using global makes it somehow go through the same loop over and over. It skips the part in dictee() where it needs to remove and append. And in check() it skips the part to add to the score. But I don't understand why.. moving the asking for input (answer), to dictee() right after the remove and append commands did not make any diffference.. It chooses a word, i can give input, but it skips the commands in between... really weird..

Comment: @OsmanPolat Could you translate the code to English and update the code?

Comment: done, thanks for taking the effort on trying to help out.

Comment: @OsmanPolat Ive updated the answer, do let me know if any more changes

Comment: Thanks! I tried that actually, but I didn't put the "words_correct, words_wrong" in global, because it was outside the function :-) also thanks for the explanation!! could you give an example on restructuring the code?

Comment: @OsmanPolat Without `words_correct` and `word_wrong` in global at `check()` the code woudnt work. Why do you want restructuring? Its better off using global than parameters here

Comment: it was more because of your comment 'I also think using parameters here might need re-structuring of your code as your calling both function from each other.' But maybe that was before your update. Thanks again for taking the effort, I highly appreciate it!

Comment: @OsmanPolat This solves all the issues right If this helped make sure to mark it as the correct answer. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to see how to mark as the answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I need to bother you again.. Now I remember another thing I encountered by putting the list outside the functions.. You cannot replay the game since the list becomes empty. Putting both vocabulary and words_passed back in dictee() somehow results in both list going to their default value. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: nevermind :-) I put the lists in main() and used global to make them available :-)

Comment: @OsmanPolat Was going to provide the same solution but instead make a function and inside the function put those lists and make them global